# Has an airplane ever been launched from a submarine?

Tags: takeoff, aircraft-carrier

Airplanes are routinely launched from [ocean going vessels](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:US_Navy_071006-N-4166B-033_An_F-A-18_Hornet_attached_to_the_Warhawks_of_Strike_Fighter_Squadron_(VFA)_97_conducts_a_touch_and_go_landing_and_takeoff_aboard_the_Nimitz-class_aircraft_carrier_USS_Abraham_Lincoln_(CVN_72).jpg), namely carriers.

[image]

Missiles are routinely launched from [submarines](http://www.navweaps.com/Weapons/WMUS_Poseidon.php).

[image]

Has an airplane ever been launched from a submarine?

From questions about what qualifies:

- Manned or unmanned is ok, but payload mass has to approximate a least a small person
- One way trip is ok
- Airboat dropped in the water is ok
- Airbreathing primary propulsion required, rocket assist for takeoff is ok
- Wings for lift are required, control fins alone do not qualify

Comment: Technically a cruise missile is a disposable aircraft (jet engine and wings, if unmanned) and modern variants can be tube launched while submerged.  Presumably the same could be done with a UAV.

Comment: @ChrisStratton A cruise missile as you describe would qualify if you can find one that actually comes from a sub. I've seen them from cruisers and destroyers.

Comment: Tomohawk would be the obvious example, with both horizontal and vertical sub launch, as well as surface ships.

Comment: This list, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_submarine-borne_aircraft seems on point...

Comment: ["Submarine aircraft carrier"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine_aircraft_carrier), Wikipedia.

Comment: How can this be a well researched question when (as pointed out by others) there is literally a wikipedia page on this very subject?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Yes,

The [HMS M2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_M2) had a single seaplane aboard that it was capable of launching.

[image]

> Her 12-inch gun was removed, replaced by a small aircraft hangar, the
>   work being completed in 1927. This could carry a small Parnall Peto
>   seaplane, specially designed for the M2, which, once its wings had
>   been unfolded, could be lowered onto the sea alongside by a derrick
>   for take off. On landing, the aircraft was hoisted back onto the deck
>   and replaced into the hangar.

...

> In October 1928, a hydraulic aircraft catapult was fitted, to enable the seaplane to take off directly from the deck.

The [I-400 class submarine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-400-class_submarine) was also capable of [aircraft launches](http://www.mastermariners.org.au/stories-from-the-past/15-submarine-aircraft-carriers).

> The type name was shortened to Toku-gata Sensuikan (特型潜水艦 Special Type
>   Submarine). **They were submarine aircraft carriers able to carry three
>   [Aichi M6A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aichi_M6A) Seiran aircraft underwater to their destinations.** They were
>   designed to surface, launch their planes, then quickly dive again
>   before they were discovered.

There are some [more info blurbs here](https://www.hazegray.org/navhist/carriers/odd/index2.htm) worth checking out about various submarine/aircraft creations.

Comment: *"once its wings had been unfolded, could be lowered onto the sea alongside by a derrick for take off"* Would seem that the aircraft was only stored on the submarine, not launched from it, although the OP would have to decide if it fits his definition of "launched from" or not. The Japanese one seems to fit the description though.

Comment: If you are willing to extend "aircraft" to include cruise missiles, the Regulus and Tomahawk missiles were launched from subs, the latter while submerged.

Comment: Are you sure 12 inch isn't a typo? That's a big number for submarine guns.

Comment: @RonBeyer Putting a boat in the water is considered launching so putting an airboat in the water has to follow, though this is not what I was originally thinking.

Comment: @Joshua not typo.  These early 1920s era submarines had dive times of 5 minutes or less... They had to function as battleships.  That 12-inch gun is actually the same gun used in Formidable-class battleships of the Royal Navy.

Comment: @Nelson "Dive times of 5 minutes or less"  What do you mean by this?  That it took them less than 5 minutes to submerge, that they could only remain submerged for 5 minutes, or something else?

Comment: Actually I did misread the dive time. It does mean it takes 5 minutes to dive. However, the thought back then is to use guns and they functioned as battleships that can submerge. Torpedoes were not reliable yet.

Comment: An underground aircraft launch can be seen about 30 seconds into this video sequence, dated 1980.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=US7IF31wDVM

Comment: Back in the late 1980's I visited the wreck of the M2 just a short distance from Portland, Dorset.  As a naval grave site it is not legal to enter the structure but it was quite impressive even though the underwater visibility was only a few metres.

Comment: Was the hanger capable of keeping the plane dry when the submarine dived? Or if they were faced with danger before they had launched the plane, did that mean they had to choose between wrecking the plane and staying on the surface?

Comment: The French [Surcouf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_submarine_Surcouf) also carried a floatplane, to spot for her twin 8-inch guns. And @Paul; depends on your definition. All these boats were designed to protect the aeroplane from water while submerged; none of them did so reliably enough for me to act as pilot.

Comment: Wow already in 1927. That must have been a feat.

Answer (score 26):

Also consider the Japanese [I-400](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-400-class_submarine) class submarine, that carried three Aichi M6A Serian bombers. Probably the most advanced aircraft carrying submarines ever built.

They entered service too late to have any meaningful impact, but the engineering that went into them was amazing for its time. Just designing a submarine that could carry a watertight aircraft hangar without the topside weight capsizing the submarine was no simple feat. They built preheaters for the aircraft engines into the submarine, so the submarine didn't have to linger on the surface while the aircraft warmed their engines.

There was a plan to attack the Panama Canal locks with torpedos launched from the Serian aircraft, but it was never carried out.

Comment: note that the I-400 was already mentioned by Dave's answer.

Comment: Plus, the U-Boot-Klasse VII could launch a "Bachstelze" somewhere near the end of the war, too.

Comment: Also this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_submarine_I-25) the only bombs to be dropped by the Japanese on the continental US were dropped by a float plane launched from a submarine.

Answer (score 18):

If you allow "airplane" = "unmanned aircraft"...then, jets!

There was [Regulus 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSM-N-8_Regulus)

> Submarine testing was performed from 1947 to 1953 at the Navy's
>   facility at Naval Air Station Point Mugu, with USS Cusk (SS-348) and
>   USS Carbonero (SS-337) converted as test platforms, initially carrying
>   the missile unprotected, thus unable to submerge until after launch.

[image]

And [Regulus II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSM-N-9_Regulus_II)

> ...the only submarine launch was carried out from USS Grayback in
>   September 1958

[image]

The air inlet on Regulus II always makes me think it's laughing for joy to be launched.

Comment: Unmanned is ok. Air breathing propulsion is required. Rocket assist for takeoff is ok.

Comment: I like these, but  where is the submarine?

Comment: The links explain that they were sub-launched.  Edited to include.

Comment: @Pilothead It's docked at Pier 86 in NYC 

Answer (score 13):

If a kite rather than an aircraft qualifies:

German U-boats used a towed autogyro to lift a lookout/pilot to a more advantageous altitude (about 120 m). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focke-Achgelis_Fa_330.

The strategy increased the visible range from 5 nautical miles to 25 nautical miles.  There is one recorded instance of a submarine detecting, attacking and sinking the Greek steamer Efthalia Mari on 6 August 1943.

If a hostile vessel was seen,

> If the U-boat captain were forced to abandon it on the surface, the tether would be released and the Fa 330 descend slowly to the water.

I believe this might discourage reports of enemy warships by the pilot/observer.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Tomahawk cruise missle] (Wikipedia)
I got beat to mentioning Regulus, but the [Tomahawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomahawk_(missile)) cruise missile has been launched from a submerged sub.  A rocket is used to initially launch the missile.
[image] ([reference](http://www.tucsonsentinel.com/nationworld/report/032711_raytheon_tomahawk/tucson-made-tomahawk-missiles-rack-up-kills-bills/))

Comment: And if you're going to complain about the "lack" of wings--those **are** wings on that missile.  It just has a very high minimum airspeed and thus can use very small wings.  They use a rocket booster to get them up to the speed where the wings will function.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

Here is a wikipedia article about many of the designs:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine_aircraft_carrier

Most seem to have gone out of service before the end of WWII, but a German submarine, the Type 212, is being designed to launch UAVs out of its mast:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_212_submarine (see the last paragraph in the "Weapons" section).

Comment: Unmanned is ok but toys do not qualify. Payload capability of the aircraft has to approximate at least a small person.