# Is is possible to have an aircraft launched from a submarine or directly from under the water?

Tags: military, aircraft-carrier

There are actually small [UAV launched by submerged submarines](https://www.nrl.navy.mil/news/releases/navy-launches-uav-submerged-submarine) and projects around [submersible aircraft](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a554344.pdf), I'm interested in a view of the current state of launching **aircraft** from submarines.

- Does anything prevent aircraft to be launched and recovered using submarines platform today?
- What is the current state of deployment of such technology around the world?

Comment: @RonBeyer: I mean today. These submarines are not what I would call indetectable.

Comment: I don't think it's possible *today*. The naval aircraft that are in use today are just too big to store inside a submarine. The F-35 is a VTOL aircraft, but only when very lightly loaded, otherwise it needs a running start. Subs also move on top of the water a lot more than aircraft carriers (not to mention not sticking out as much), which almost necessitates water landings and long recoveries (hoisting). I don't think this can be done with what we have today.

Comment: This is a pretty big change in the question; I'm not sure the existing answers are still valid answers to the question in its new form.

Comment: @ZeissIkon: I've extended to submersible aircraft, else this is still about submersible carrier, today, as before it was reopened.

Comment: Aircraft? Yes. cruise missiles. Direct-launch cruise missiles especially has been widely deployed since the 70s.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has an airplane ever been launched from a submarine?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/53142/has-an-airplane-ever-been-launched-from-a-submarine)

Comment: @Pilothead: Not really, the other question talks about WW2 era or missiles.

Comment: @Pilothead: Closely related, but _not_ a duplicate (this one asks if it's possible, the other asks if it's actually been _done_).

Comment: @Sean: Thanks for explaining, but I guess this won't be understood by the usual closists. Don't worry.

Answer (score 9):

The Japanese navy did that in WW2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-400-class_submarine

Answer (score 2):

The Regulus missile was a (pilotless) aircraft launched from American submarines in the 1950s -- it in turn was a nuclear armed upgrade of the Hermes, which was a captured, and later copied, German buzz-bomb launched from a deck catapult.

As noted in another answer, the Japanese built a small number of very large submarines with a sealed hangar on the deck; each carried and could catapult launch (as I recall) three Zero or similar aircraft equipped with floats, which would land alongside and be hoisted back aboard.  These subs never saw significant service, as Japan surrendered while the first was on it's first mission near South America.

Modern (nuclear) submarines are highly optimized for submerged operation, and aren't steady enough on the surface to launch and recover piloted aircraft even if modified to carry something like a Harrier or F-35, but there's no reason drones couldn't be launched (brought on deck through the escape trunk, deck hatch, or sail) and, in the case of hovering types, recovered while surfaced.

Comment: Interesting. Yes there are [drones launched from submarine](https://www.nrl.navy.mil/news/releases/navy-launches-uav-submerged-submarine), though I'm interested in larger aircraft, and perhaps related technologies such as [submersible aircraft](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a554344.pdf).

Comment: Aren't all cruise missiles pilotless aircraft?

Comment: Yep.  And Tomahawks launched from torpedo tubes can give attack subs (*Los Angeles* class) nuclear capability.  But you generally don't want to recover a Tomahawk at the originating vessel...